# number.ToString(formatString) isn't working

Tags: c#

In .NET 7, why are none of the calls to ToString with a format string working? They all return the full number.

```
var number = 123456L;

var myString = number.ToString("d3"); // 123456
var myString = number.ToString("D3"); // 123456
var myString2 = number.ToString("000"); // 123456
```

Expectation:

```
number.ToString("d1"); // 1
number.ToString("d2"); // 12
number.ToString("d3"); // 123
number.ToString("d4"); // 1234
number.ToString("d5"); // 12345
number.ToString("d6"); // 123456
```

Note: The number is a `long`. It doesn't work if it's an `int` either.

Comment: What do you *want* it to return?

Comment: The field length is a *minimum*. If the number is large, it would be impossible to display it otherwise.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#decimal-format-specifier-d) on what the format specifiers do? These are the expected results.

Comment: _"isn't working"_ is most of the time people mistakingly expecting different results than the ones they are (correctly according to specs) getting. Are you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`D` and `d` do the same thing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#DFormatString):

> The precision specifier indicates the **minimum** number of digits desired in the resulting string. **If required**, the number is padded with zeros to its left to produce the number of digits given by the precision specifier.

So, it will pad the number with zeros to read the specified minimum length if necessary:

```
123.ToString("D4"); // 0123
12345.ToString("D4"); // 12345
```

The [`0` format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the-0-custom-specifier) does pretty much the same thing:

> If the value that is being formatted has a digit in the position where the zero appears in the format string, that digit is copied to the result string; otherwise, a zero appears in the result string.

So "0000" is the same as "D4", see above.

---

From your edit, it looks like you want to take the specified number of digits, and ignore all further digits.

There isn't a built-in string format specifier to do this, however some simple maths can help:

```
long GetLeadingDigits(long input, int numDigits)
{
    int numDigitsInInput = (int)Math.Ceiling(Math.Log10(input));
    return (int)(input / Math.Pow(10, numDigitsInInput - numDigits));
}
```

Then:

```
long number = 123456L;
GetLeadingDigits(number, 1); // 1
GetLeadingDigits(number, 6); // 123456
GetLeadingDigits(number, 7); // 1234560
```

Alternatively, you can solve this with strings:

```
string GetLeadingDigits(long input, int numDigits)
{
    return input.ToString().Substring(0, numDigits)
}
```

Comment: Thanking you. I read the docs but missed that part. I'm trying to format a custom time the same way DateTime does it with the 'f' string format. I got it working using Substring.

Comment: Note that `f` denotes a **fraction**. The equivalent for floats would be `F`, e.g. `1.2345.ToString("F3")` gives 1.234`

Answer (score 1):

Your expectation is betraying the value. 123456 is not 1.

As said in the comments, the field length is only a minimum and might not be fulfilled. To achieve the result that you want, you can simply trim the string.